# How to recover android

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My android Tablet PC eklasse Spark 4.0.3 7" Black Model No:ES01120905934.

Unfortunately using cleaner app some system file are deleted.

Can any one give me a suggestion what can i do now.

i can't found ROM of Frameware file in web to reboot.

Comment: cc Cleaner. i dont know the karnel version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Backup, just *Restore it*.

or, there is **two way** :

Use something like :  `EASEUS Data Recovery Wizard Professional`

> //for Recovery...

or another way ;

Download the rom and flash it for fix.

[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Comment: i ve no idea where to find ROM for my device.